# The jquery selector for input only works for the first element

Tags: jquery, string, replace, selector, bigcommerce

First of all, what I'm trying to achieve is replace a string on bigcommerce checkout page. I'm trying to replace payment method name in the checkout page under 5th step which is order confirmation . I can't simply change the text string in html file since it's all load from bigcommerce server by express checkout feature.

What I did so far is using css :after trick to replace it. However it's not compatible with IE since it's a input field. So the only option left is using javascript.

This is the current coding I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.ChangeLink, input[type='submit']") .live("click", function() {

$('label.ProviderNamecheckout_eway:contains("eWay Australia")').text('Credit Card');

});
});
```

It's current works fine when I click on the first input button of the first section. Also the modify link on the right all the time. But it's not working on the section which I need the most. on the shipping selection section, I would like to trigger this replace function when I click on the continue button. But it's not working.

Please help!!!

**Update:** did some changes on the code and now at least the click event works on the new appended elements. But still the replace won't work. I think the reason is the replace triggers before the append element fully load. So it can't locate the correct element ID.

**Update:** Problem solved, not by javascript at the end. Just found a way to change the payment name on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Your `click` should be defined inside the ready and you have defined the `ready` inside the click which makes no sense, `ready` will be called in the end of when page loads and you are trying the ready to call when click event fires

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.ChangeLink, input") .click(function() {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");    

        //$('label.ProviderNamecheckout_eway').replaceWith('Credit Card');
        $('label.ProviderNamecheckout_eway').text('Credit Card'); 
        // or $('label.ProviderNamecheckout_eway').html('Credit Card');
    });
});
```

Finally got your problem you have to play with you `css` in IE mode remove these two css then script will work perfectly as currently it does but it not showing the text because you have used `visibility: hidden;`  so move these css if condition when not in IE

```
.ProviderNamecheckout_eway {
visibility: hidden;
}
.ProviderNamecheckout_eway:after {
content: "Credit Card";
position: relative;
right: 106px;
visibility: visible;
display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, that's what I tried at first and it's not working at all. The reason behind this it's because the string i'm trying to alter is not loaded on the first load of the page. Those content are added after I click on the continue button on the 4th step which is the shipping selection. That is why I put document.ready inside. I know it's may sounds like stupid, but it at least works when I'm click on the modify button. I tried us .load function but unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: @user2549386 see  my updated answer use `text()` or `html()` instead of `replaceWith`

Comment: can you provide any live url

Comment: I'll try the new update codes and let you know the result. thanks a lot!!

Comment: I just tried both, unfortunately it's not working. I think the problem is the even listener is not triggering at the first place so the modification is not going to work as well. The first step is to make the continue input button at the step4 shipping methods been detected, then trigger the replace or any modification functions to the string. Thanks for your help:)

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs. I did exactly what you specified in your respond. But it's not working. Actually that's what I did in the first place when I'm trying to achieve it without css at all. I use css to solve this issue afterwards when I found out the jquery doesn't work. I could use '$('label.ProviderNamecheckout_eway').replaceWith('Credit Card');' a single line of the code in the console to make it work when testing in either chrome or firefox developer console but the main point is the current code only works for the page at first load. The target is the additional content on dynamic.

Comment: For example, if I run '$('label.ProviderNamecheckout_eway').replaceWith('Credit Card');' in console when I'm on the 5th checkout step which is order confirm page. This code would work, but it's triggering only because the content already there. The document.ready only run once when I'm inside the check out page and it's ignore all the additional contents loaded afterwards. That is the mean issue and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: The proper theory I could thought about is:
1st: a event listener able to detect the additional content has been loaded.
2nd: the targeting content has been fully loaded.
3rd: replace the content.